# How can I make a value in MongoDB only be set once?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How can I check if a value exists on "timestamp", and if it doesn't exist I want it to update it but if the value exists I want it to leave it alone?

Comment: I have an Object called "firstUsed" and I want MongoDB to check if it exists and if it doesn't I want it to set a value called "currentTimestamp" but if it does exist I want it to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First look for the value. If it doesn't exist create it, else do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a field called `_id`.  This field is special as it is the only field in mongo that is immutable. Also, this field is mandatory.  If you do not specify a value it will default to a new ObjectId() value.

If this timestamp value you wish to save is actually the record creation date time then simply use the default ObjectId() value.  The ObjectId is a special type that has an embedded timestamp value within it.

Here is how you would see the timestamp of an ObjectId() using the mongo shell...

**MongoShell View Date and Time of ObjectId**

```
var x = new ObjectId();
x.getTimestamp();
```

**Results**

```
> x.getTimestamp();
ISODate("2021-10-06T22:12:50Z")
```

Having this field an immutable field your primary objective is covered.  You have a timestamp and a field that cannot be modified.  The problem is having an undefined value for some period of time.  I would need more clarity on how the record would not have a timestamp...